# How do you build a docker container from an image?

Tags: docker

I have a mysql docker image w/ id: **fb86ef4dd8b7**

What is the command to build a container and name it using the above docker-image: **MY_NEW_CONTAINER**

"docker build -t MY_NEW_CONTAINER..." but how do I specify to use the above docker image?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking, maybe you are looking for the `tag` subcommand? https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/tag/

Comment: `docker run` will create a container from your image. `docker build` is used to build an image.

Comment: you can try docker commit to creating new from existing one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A container is a running copy of an image. So to create a container from an inage, you simply [`docker run`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/) it.

You can give the container a name (instead of the auto-generated scientist name) with the `--name` option.

```
docker run --name mysql_container_1 fb86ef4dd8b7
```

Why doesn't your image have a name? You should [`docker tag`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/tag/) it.

Comment: @user2915097 Edited, thanks. You can delete your comment now if you'd like.